# Get promotion like plugin or jquery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Is there any plugin for wordpress to add a shape with animation effect on hover like the image
[image]

OR may be jquery to add something like that also to add to the top right of my home page ?

Answer (score 1):

There you go: [Sexy Curls jQuery Plugin](http://elliottkember.com/sexy_curls.html)

Fun fact: In German, we call such a thing "Eselsohr" ("donkey ear"), so I knew what to google for ;)

Comment: Thanks that what i really wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I should paste the whole code 
but here's a demo:

**[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ovawiv/2/edit)**

you can use a .png image instead of my rotated gray DIV (I was lazy)

and use a simple script like:

```
$('#ad').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function( e ){
    var paper = $('#ad-paper', this);
    var pos = e.type=='mouseenter'? 380 : 260;
  paper.stop().animate({left: -pos},300);
});
```

to achieve the movements.